# JQuery on initial browser width not working properly (only works when resized)

Tags: jquery, browser, width

The code below is used as an alternative to using media queries for browser width and modifying the css file for various moble widths.  However, when the code is run for the furst time (when the website loads), the condition: (width >= 767) && (width < 1042) loads first on all widths less than 1042.  For instance, if the width is 400, the medium2.css will be used.

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 1042) {
        $(".leftNavigationBox").hide();
    }
    if (width < 440) {
        $(".container").hide();
        $("#sizestylesheet").attr("href", "/Styles/Reallynarrow3.css");
    } else if ((width > 441) && (width < 767)) {
        $(".container").hide();
        $("#sizestylesheet").attr("href", "/Styles/narrow2.css");
    } else if ((width > 768) && (width < 1042)) {
        $(".container").hide();
        $("#sizestylesheet").attr("href", "/Styles/Medium2.css");
    } else {
        $(".leftNavigationBox").show();
        $(".container").show();
        $("#sizestylesheet").attr("href", "/Styles/SiteNew28.css");
    }
}

$(function () {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function () {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a quick check, do you have <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of your html file? If you dont, jquery will go into quirks mode and width/height wont work properly.

Comment: Yes sir, I do indeed.  <!DOCTYPE html>.  Should I use a more relevant declaration?

Comment: No, that just could of been a problem. However, @Moob's answer looks right to me. `this` in Javascript is quite tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` refers to the jQuery object to which the event or method is attached.

`$(function(){` is shorthand for [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), so on the first call `$(this)` refers to the `document`. On resize `$(this)` refers to the `window`.

To fix the issue, simply pass the `$(window).width()` rather than `$(this)` to your `adjustStyle()` method on first call.

```
$(function () {
    adjustStyle($(window).width());
    $(window).resize(function () {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of why you think this will work? You're not helping very much by just throwing code around.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  You are correct, the "this" was ambiguous in the code and probably related to something other than the window. Thank you for recommending the explicit form.